# File Upload Vulnerability SVG

Tags: file-upload, image, svg

I am currently doing a bug bounty program and was testing the company's file upload functionality. After meddling with the functionality for a while, I was able to change the extension of the uploaded file to '.svg' using burpsuite. I have read tons of article saying that .svg files is equal to XSS. In my case I was not able to fully upload svg file since the server is checking the content of the file. I have change the 'Content-Type' to image/svg and the file is uploaded, but when I change the content of the file with XML Tags, the server denied my upload. I found out that in order for the file to be uploaded successful, the beginning of the content type should be '...JFIF' which is a metadata to describe that the content is JPEG/PNG and is interchangable. I have tried appending the SVG XML tag after the metadata and has successfully uploaded it to the server, but when the image is opened, a square image appeared and my XML tags are not being executed.

Is there any way I could bypass this image content to be able to execute XML? Is there any metada for SVG perhaps?

[image: The broken image]

this image can be accessed from https://[redacted]/avt/131231/original/filename.svg

Comment: I couldn't write the first part of the metadata but it is = 'ÿØÿà'

Comment: "I have read tons of article saying that .svg files is equal to XSS" that's nonsense. You need to understand what you're reading and doing.

Comment: There are too few details to determine how the site you test behaves in detail and how exactly you are testing. In any case: script inside the svg will not be executed if the svg is embedded with img tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, What I read is that since .svg files are made up of XML tags, therefore it is possible, in most scenarios, to have a script tag and therefore have stored XSS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the description I provided is the most I could get from testing the file upload. To clarify: 1. I was able to upload '.svg' file with JFIF content by intercepting the request through burp and changing the extension | 2. The file upload is only possible if 'JFIF' metadata is present | 3. I tried adding the XML tags after the JFIF metadata and access the image but it returns a small white square border

Comment: @EmanuelBeni: *"... but when the image is opened..."* - you did not specify how the SVG is finally accessed. Did you access it directly or was it embedded into an img tag? If access directly, what Content-type was provided by the server. Was the file served from the server the same as you uploaded or was the content changed (this is about the actual bytes not about some visual representation).

Comment: @EmanuelBeni: Could you please answer the other questions I've asked in the comment too? And could you please edit your question to include all these relevant details so that others don't need to dig into the comments in the hope to find more useful information than the question provides?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I am sorry for the vague explanation. The SVG is finally accessed through a link since images that are being uploaded are being stored in a subdomain own by the company. E.g 'https://[redacted]/avt/213123/original/filename.svg'. As for response Content-Type, 'image/jpeg' is being returned by the server. I believe this is because of the metadata in the content. I have added the broken image in my question above. Note: My keyboard messed up, wanted to change line but posted the comment instead

Comment: I don't think that screenshot is really adding very much, but I also don't think there is a vulnerability here.  As has been pointed out, an SVG != XSS.  In this case in particular the fact that the upload is only possible with the JFIF metadata means that they are properly enforcing a JPG image type.  When you add that to the top of your SVG you no longer have an SVG - you have a corrupt JPG with a `.svg` extension.  That wouldn't give you XSS even if you an SVG did mean XSS (which it usually doesn't).  Remember that it isn't the extension that determines the type of file, but the contents.

Comment: @ConorMancone, Thank you for the clear explanation. Much appreciated!